How to reset values and IDs of input elements which are inside TD elements of a table after dynamically deleting row with jQuery?
I have following table:
<thead>
      <th>SR</th>
      <th>Object</th>
      <th>Weight</th>
      <th>Color</th>
      <th>Shape</th>
      <th>DeleteBtn</th>
</thead>
<tr>
      <td><input type="text" id="sr1" value="1" class="sr"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="object1" value="toy"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="weight1" value="5kg"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="color1" value="green"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="shape1" value="round"></td>
      <td><input type="button" class="deleteRow"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
      <td><input type="text" id="sr2" value="2"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="object2" value="bottle"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="weight2" value="1kg"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="color2" value="red"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="shape2" value="cylinder"></td>
      <td><input type="button" class="deleteRow"></td>
</tr>
</table>

The above code is just for illustration. These rows are getting generated dynamically using php, ajax, jQuery. Second column input element also has autocomplete function based on which other columns are populated for each row. Also IDs of each input elements are important for further complex operations data.
I have set code for adding row which assign next sequential value to new generated row for SR column and also generates new rows with IDs sequentially for each row.
But I am facing problem to reset SR value and IDs in sequence after deleting a row, as user can delete row anywhere in between.
How can I reset value attribute of input tag inside SR column in sequence and also assign sequential IDs to each input elements of each row based on new number of rows, as shown in above code?

No this code is just for example. I have working code for rest of the operations like autocomplete operation on object column which based on input access data from database and after clicking selected suggestion sets that value to object columns and auto populates rest of the columns in a given row. In some cases whole of the table is auto populated based on some other input value from element outside the table. All these codes are designed to set IDs of input elements as shown in the format I have posted. I don't wish to change all that code now just to achieve this requirement.

I can get number of rows now present in Table after deleting a row. I am stuck at how to access each input element from each TD of each TR and set its ID attribute to desired number by running a loop. There can be any number of rows to start with and user can delete any number of rows in between the table or at start or at end of table. I can not use the already assigned IDs as for example after deleting a middle row some input tags will have IDs in sequence like 1,3,4,7 etc. Is there a way to access each input element in each TD of each row using index?

You have to add id field and data-id attribute to  each table row and delete button like below

<tr id="tr_1" data-id="1">
      <td><input type="text" id="sr1" value="1" class="sr"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="object1" value="toy"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="weight1" value="5kg"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="color1" value="green"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="shape1" value="round"></td>
      <td><input type="button" data-id="1" class="deleteRow"></td>
</tr>


which corresponds to sr1 which is unique for all rows. when you execute delete command through JavaScript or jQuery
you can use jquery remove() function to remove row

$('.deleterow').click(function(){
   var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
   $('#tr_'+id).remove(); 
});


to update value of input fields in each row 
you can implement same id attribute and access elements like

 
     $('#object'+id).val('any value');
     $('#weight'+id).val('any value');
     $('#color'+id).val('any value');

also while adding  row you can generate  unique no for id using php rand(); or JavaScript  Math.random();  and insert row which can be used to do further actions.
sequential id is not necessary. if necessary please comment to add code for that also.
You can iterate over rows and access their child elements in td

 $("tr").each(function() {
    var id= $(this).attr('data-id');
    var sr = $(this).find("input#sr"+id).val(),
    var object = $(this).find("input#object"+id).val();
    var weight = $(this).find("input#weight"+id).val();
     
    //........
    /// and so on.
 });


